# Problem with showing featured image

Tags: post-thumbnails, excerpt

I am using the code below for showing featured image in single post content.It's working fine.But when I call the_excerpt(); in any template it showing featured image with post content.I want it show featured image only single post.Please help!

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'put_thumbnail_in_posting' ); 
function put_thumbnail_in_posting($content) { 
    global $post; 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ( $post->post_type == 'post' ) ) {
        the_post_thumbnail( '',
            array(
                'style' => 'padding: 6px;
                margin-bottom: 8px;
                margin-right: 8px;
                max-width: 100%;
                border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
                background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(238, 238, 238);'
            )
        );
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: I gather you want to display your post thumbnail in your RSS feed as well?

Answer (score 1):

Use an `is_single()` condition to ensure the thumbnail isn't added on archive pages. You should also be using `get_the_post_thumbnail` and prepending it to `$content`, rather than just echo'ing it out:

```
function put_thumbnail_in_posting( $content ) { 
    if ( is_single() && has_post_thumbnail() && get_post_type() == 'post' ) {
        $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail( null, '',
            array(
                'style' => implode( ' ',
                    array(
                        'padding: 6px;',
                        'margin-bottom: 8px;',
                        'margin-right: 8px;',
                        'max-width: 100%;',
                        'border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);',
                        'background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(238, 238, 238);',
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        $content = $thumbnail . $content;
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 add_filter( 'the_content', 'put_thumbnail_in_posting' ); 
 function put_thumbnail_in_posting( $content ) { 
    if ( is_singular('post') && is_main_query() && has_post_thumbnail()) {
        $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail( null, '',
            array(
                'style' => implode( ' ',
                    array(
                        'padding: 6px;',
                        'margin-bottom: 8px;',
                        'margin-right: 8px;',
                        'max-width: 100%;',
                        'border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);',
                        'background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(238, 238, 238);',
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        $content = $thumbnail . $content;
    }

    return $content;
}
```

This code includes the [`is_singular('post')`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) conditional tag which controls the display of the featured image in single posts only.

[`the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) hook filters the_content, [gets the post thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) if one has been added to the post using the featured image module and displays it then adds the content after the image.

You could code this differently and also add a fallback featured image in your child themes images folder which displays if one isn't added manually.

```
 add_filter( 'the_content', 'put_thumbnail_in_posting' ); 
 function put_thumbnail_in_posting( $content ) { 
    if ( is_singular('post') && is_main_query() && has_post_thumbnail()) {
        $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail( null, '',
            array(
                'style' => implode( ' ',
                    array(
                        'padding: 6px;',
                        'margin-bottom: 8px;',
                        'margin-right: 8px;',
                        'max-width: 100%;',
                        'border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);',
                        'background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(238, 238, 238);',
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        $content = $thumbnail . $content;

        }

        else echo'<img src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/fallback.jpg' . '" alt="" />';

    return $content;
}
```

The 2nd code block includes a fallback featured image.

Here's another way to code it:

```
 add_filter( 'the_content', 'featured_image_before_content' ); 

 function featured_image_before_content( $content ) { 
    if ( is_singular('post') && is_main_query() && has_post_thumbnail()) {
        $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail();

        $content = $thumbnail . $content;

        }

    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If featured Image not working. Dont worry you can download this [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-featured-images) install it and use it. i works easily for you. visit for more [tutorials about wordpress and seo](http://www.topseobuzz.com)

Comment: Please provide an short relevant description and code for example from the link given.